# How to sort certain coordinates based on status [0,1]

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

i was wondering how do i get the coordinates from the status '0' or 'EMPTY' out of all the data given.

```
 var locations = [
    ['FULL',3.720185, 103.124075,1],
    ['EMPTY',3.719693, 103.123896,0],
    ['FULL',3.720916, 103.12492,1],
    ['EMPTY',3.721032, 103.124532,0],
    ['FULL',3.722299, 103.124587,1],
    ['FULL',3.723189, 103.124706,1],
    ['FULL',3.725067, 103.124593,1]
    ];

    for (var k=0;k<locations.length; k++)
    {
        if (locations[i][3]==0) {
        var diff=getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude,locations[k][1],locations[k][2]);
        x.innerHTML = "<h1>Distance of nearest bin: "+ Math.min(diff)+"km</h1>";
        }
```

this is what i tried so far.

Comment: please add what you want, either filtering or sorting? and what happens with [0, 1]? what does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), passing a predicate function that checks whether each location array has a first element equal to `EMPTY` or fourth element equal to `0` (which is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)):

```js
var locations = [
  ['FULL', 3.720185, 103.124075, 1],
  ['EMPTY', 3.719693, 103.123896, 0],
  ['FULL', 3.720916, 103.12492, 1],
  ['EMPTY', 3.721032, 103.124532, 0],
  ['FULL', 3.722299, 103.124587, 1],
  ['FULL', 3.723189, 103.124706, 1],
  ['FULL', 3.725067, 103.124593, 1]
]

var result = locations.filter(function (e) {
  return e[0] === 'EMPTY' || !e[3]
})

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the locations:

```js
var locations = [
  ['FULL', 3.720185, 103.124075, 1],
  ['EMPTY', 3.719693, 103.123896, 0],
  ['FULL', 3.720916, 103.12492, 1],
  ['EMPTY', 3.721032, 103.124532, 0],
  ['FULL', 3.722299, 103.124587, 1],
  ['FULL', 3.723189, 103.124706, 1],
  ['FULL', 3.725067, 103.124593, 1]
];

var emptyLocations = locations.filter(function(location) {
  return location[0] === 'EMPTY' || location[3] === 0;
});

console.log(emptyLocations);
// [["EMPTY", 3.719693, 103.123896, 0], ["EMPTY", 3.721032, 103.124532, 0]]
```